# Which type of client id to create for android app using google cloud storage

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-storage

I am planning to use the JSON API to upload an image to google cloud SQL from Android. I am confused on what type of client id to create for authentication. The link https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage talks about creating a service account id ,but the link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples talks about creating an installed application id. Although the second type sounds reasonable for an Android application, most working samples have used a service account . Creating a client id for service account is easier than the other too.

So i would like to know what each of these are for and which one to use .Also ,If anyone has any working samples using the latest JSON v1 API, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an installed application ID will be more appropriate for this setup, as service accounts are only meant for server-to-server interaction.